# Issue with ExtractValue function of mysql

Tags: mysql, extract-value

```
 set @xml = '<a>demo</a>';
 select extractvalue(@xml ,'/a');
```

I want to extract value for both the string with 
 `< a > demo< /a >` and `< a > demo < /a >` at the same time.

Is it possible using lower-case function or something. I want to extract values with case-insensitiveness for xml tags.

Answer (score 0):

XML is case-sensitive, `<a>` and `<A>` are different tags. You can use a disjunct:

```
set @xml = '<a>demo</a>';
select extractvalue(@xml ,'/A|/a');
```

Or, better yet, normalise your XML.

Comment: but what to do  in case of < destiNation > 8989 < /destiNation > and < destination > 8989 < /destination >  ?

Comment: You fire whoever made the XML file, then normalise the file. Go through every node and replace its name by a canonical one (e.g. by lowercasing them). If `destiNation` and `destination` denote the same kind of information, such an XML file should never have entered your database in the first place. It's like driving a taxi professionally with a bicycle tyre, a truck tyre, a car tyre and a dinner plate for your wheels.